# RxJS: forkJoin isn't returning

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently working on an `Angular App v7+` with `Typescript v3.1.3` using `RxJS v6.3.1`.
My problem is, that I want to return a forkjoin with an observable array.

That's what my Code looks like:

```
getPlacesToShowForkJoin(location: GeoPoint, radius: number, dateRange: DateRange): Observable<Place[]> {

    return this.getPlacesInRadius(location, radius).pipe(
      switchMap( (places: GeoQueryDocument[]) => {
        const availablePlaces = places.map( (place: GeoQueryDocument) => {
          return this.getAvailablePlaces(dateRange, place.id).pipe(
            map((bookings: Booking[]) => {
                //removed code for better overview
                return wantedObject;
              }
            })
          );
        });
        return forkJoin(availablePlaces);
      })
    );
  }
```

I'm subscribing to `getPlacesToShowForkJoin`, but it's never called.
When I console log the `availablePlaces`, I see the array including 5 observables.

Am I missing something or did I completely misunderstood anything?

Comment: Check what you have on the `next` function on the `getPlacesToShowForkJoin.subscribe((value) => console.log(value))`. Do you have a value you can subscribe to? If that's the case, then the `forkJoin` is not being subscribed to.

Comment: I already `subscribed` to the function. But there is no value. I tried it with `combinedLatest` and it worked. But I don't get why it doesn't with `forkJoin`

Comment: I just tried with `forkJoin` and it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z1gewc?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: As you can see in the console, there's an array of objects returned by `forkJoin`

Comment: Could it be possible that an Observable returned from a method have another behaviour then an Observable made with `of([x,y,z])`. Because it works for me also with `of`

Comment: Not really sure. Could be, depending on the type of observable. What do you have in your case? What `of` does is, it emits the value(s) and the completes. Nothing more special than that.

Comment: For `forkJoin` to emit a value, all of the observables passed to it must emit at least one value and must complete.

Comment: make sure when you subscribe you add an error handler.  Most likely your `removed code for better overview` is throwing an Error